# Elasticsearch - How to combine bool and range filters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I would like to combine this bool filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "tp_operacao": "D"
        }}}}}
```

and this range filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "nr_autorizacao": {
        "gte": 0
  }}}}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put filter as array

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tp_operacao": "D"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "nr_autorizacao": {
              "gte": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```